# Is there an equation to easily convert a color to its matching color in another hue?

Tags: color, color-theory, color-profile, hex

I am trying to design a site with a couple color schemes. I am looking for a way to make color schemes that match mathematically.

For example, I know that `#FF0000` matches perfectly with `#00FF00` and `#0000FF`. Is there some kind of equation to get, for example, the yellow version of `#509cc0`? I also have the RGB values and the HSL values on hand.

Comment: I assume you mean automatically? It should be pretty easy using HSL - you just change the Hue value (the 'H' in HSL) to the appropriate value or by the appropriate amount. [Wikipedia has a formula for how to convert HSL to RGB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#From_HSL) which could be done after, and the hex #00FF00 code is just the RGB value in hexadecimal (base 16) format. Someone more mathematical than me could probably turn this into an answer...

Comment: Actually, that makes a lot of sense as far as changing the Hue value. The only problem is finding the right value to change it to.

Comment: @user568458 I'd post that as an answer!

Comment: Should the question be something like "how to change hue of a RGB colour while keeping saturation and lightness the same?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm wary of purely mathematical approaches to color harmony; numbers have no aesthetic sensibilities. That said, since the Hue wheel is divided into 360 degrees, one can build a complementary color scheme by adding 180 to the hue for any given color, a triadic by adding and subtracting 120, and so on.

The triadics below were done using simple arithmetic in the H field of the Photoshop color picker, adding 120 to the value each time. Pure RGB above (in reverse sequence, sorry!), and your starter color, #509cc0 in the row below.

[image: Triadic colors calculated in HSB]

Comment: That's exactly the answer I was looking for. I think this will be perfect, thanks!